# Should I use “the” after 'received'?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentences grammatically correct?

> John Smith was born in Netherlands, on the 21st of May 1981.
>   He received **the** B.Eng. degree in Computer Science with specialization
>   in Network Engineering from The Hague University of Applied Sciences,
>   Hague, Netherlands, in 2013.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not. You should say he received `a` Bachelor's of Engineering degree, not `the`. I'm not sure 100% the reason, but I think you tend to use `the` if the thing you are talking about is the subject of the phrase, and it's a specific one.

For instance:

`The Bachelor's of Engineering he earned gave Timmy many opportunities.`

However, a similar sentence without it being a specific degree we're talking about could be:

`A Bachelor's of Engineering degree can give you many opportunities.`

Hope that helps!